# r - ggplot2 - highlighting selected points and strange behavior

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to highlight selected points and encountered some strange behaviour. First some dummy data:

```
a <- 1:50
b <- rnorm(50)
mydata <- data.frame(a=a,b=b)
ggplot(mydata,aes(x=a,y=b)) + geom_point()
```

This works correctly. Now,to highlight some points, I add another `geom_point` layer:

```
ggplot(mydata[20:40,],aes(x=a,y=b)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_point(aes(x=a[c(10,12,13)],y=b[c(10,12,13)]),colour="red")
```

Note that I am displaying only a limited range of the data (`[20:40]`).  Now comes the strange behavior:

```
ggplot(mydata[10:40,],aes(x=a,y=b)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_point(aes(x=a[c(10,12,13)],y=b[c(10,12,13)]),colour="red")
```

Changing the size of the selected range, I get an error, roughly translated from German: `Error...: Arguments implying different number of rows`. Strangely, this varies with the selected range. `[23:40]` will work, `[22:40]` won't.

---

The error in English is:

```
Error in data.frame(x = c(19L, 21L, 22L), y = c(0.28198, -0.6215,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 31
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I've added the error in English

Answer (score 43):

If your data is different between different layers, then you need to specify the new data for each layer.

You do this with the `data=...` argument for each `geom` that needs different data:

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(a=1:50, b=rnorm(50))
ggplot(mydata,aes(x=a,y=b)) + 
  geom_point(colour="blue") +
  geom_point(data=mydata[10:13, ], aes(x=a, y=b), colour="red", size=5)
```

[image]

Comment: Well, the data is not actually different, just a different subset. But this solution is at least stable. Works only with explicit naming (`data=...`). But no explanation for that strange error...

Comment: @lambu0815 The fact that it's a different subset makes it different. You had that strange error because you tried to map a single aesthetic (x) to three different elements. Aesthetics must be mapped to column names. You also don't have to explicitly name the `data=...` argument, but then you need to have the arguments in the correct order, i.e. `geom_point(aes(...), data, ...)`

Answer (score 8):

Another option adding the conditions for both attributes, colour and size, inside `geom_point`. Then we control manually those using `scale_colour_manual` and `scale_size_manual` respectively.

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(a = 1:50, b = rnorm(50))
ggplot(mydata) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = a, y = b, colour = a > 9 & a < 14, size = a > 9 & a < 14)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) + 
  scale_size_manual(values =c(1, 4))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another solution with [gghighlight](http://yutani.rbind.io/post/2017-10-06-gghighlight/):

```
a <- 1:50
b <- rnorm(50)
mydata <- data.frame(a=a,b=b, type = sample(letters, 50, replace = T))

library(gghighlight)
gghighlight_point(mydata, aes(x=a, y=b), label_key = type, 
                  a <= 14 & a >= 10 & b >= 0 , col="red")
```