# Adding table within the plotting region of a ggplot in r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to add a table of the coordinates of highlighted site in a ggplot.

Using a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467965/r-ggplot2-highlighting-selected-points-and-strange-behavior) as example data:

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(a=1:50, b=rnorm(50))
ggplot(mydata,aes(x=a,y=b)) + 
    geom_point(colour="blue") + 
    geom_point(data=mydata[10:13, ], aes(x=a, y=b), colour="red", size=5)
```

[image]

I would like to add the following table to the lower right-hand corner of the plot within the plotting region. Any advice?

```
table<-cbind(sites=c("site 1","site 2","site 3","site 4"),mydata[10:13,])
table

    sites  a          b
    site 1 10 -0.3053884
    site 2 11  1.5117812
    site 3 12  0.3898432
    site 4 13 -0.6212406
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can use `ggplot2`'s  `annotation_custom` with a `tableGrob` from the `gridExtra` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(a=1:50, b=rnorm(50))
mytable <- cbind(sites=c("site 1","site 2","site 3","site 4"),mydata[10:13,])
k <- ggplot(mydata,aes(x=a,y=b)) + 
  geom_point(colour="blue") + 
  geom_point(data=mydata[10:13, ], aes(x=a, y=b), colour="red", size=5) + 
  annotation_custom(tableGrob(mytable), xmin=35, xmax=50, ymin=-2.5, ymax=-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I'd chop at least four of the decimals from `b` though, unless you really care about 1 part in 10,000 precision (hint: you don't unless flying to Mars).

Comment: @mplourde Thank you! This is a very nice and straight forward solution. To make the table stand out better is it possible to put a frame around it?

Comment: take a look at `?tableGrob` to see the aesthetics you can control. Using `show.box=TRUE` will frame the cells.

Comment: control over aesthetics has changed in the last release, see [the vignette](https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki/tableGrob) for the various new options.

Comment: is it possible to remove the row numbers while displaying it ?

Comment: is it possible to specify relative positioning , rather than absolute ?

Comment: @user3206440 I don't believe so. You can use `Inf` and `-Inf` to push it to the extremities or the center, but it will fall outside of the plot region.

Answer (score 25):

With the release of ['ggplot2'](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ggplot2)  3.0.0 and ['ggpmisc'](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ggpmisc)  0.3.0 a new simpler answer is possible:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(a = 1:50, b = rnorm(50))
table <- cbind(sites=c("site 1", "site 2", "site 3", "site 4"), mydata[10:13, ])

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = a, y = b)) + 
  geom_point(colour = "blue") + 
  geom_point(data = mydata[10:13, ], aes(x = a, y = b), colour = "red", size = 5) +
  annotate(geom = "table", x = 37, y = -0.8, label = list(table), 
           vjust = 1, hjust = 0)
```

'ggplot2' 3.0.0 fully supports tibbles (see [release announcement](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-3-0-0/)) making it possible to map a list of data frames to the `label` aesthetic. The new `geom_table()` in package 'ggpmisc 0.3.0' takes advantage of this, making the addition of tables with a syntax similar to that of `geom_label()` possible (see [documentation](https://docs.r4photobiology.info/ggpmisc/reference/geom_table.html)). Here seemed most appropriate to add the table as an
annotation, but of course `geom_table()` can also be used directly, as other `ggplot` geometries.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

@user3206440, @Punintended An easy way of removing row numbers exists: add `rows = NULL` to the call to `tableGrob`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(a=1:50, b=rnorm(50))
mytable <- 
   cbind(sites=c("site 1","site 2","site 3","site 4"), mydata[10:13,])
k <- ggplot(mydata,aes(x=a,y=b)) + 
  geom_point(colour="blue") + 
  geom_point(data=mydata[10:13, ], aes(x=a, y=b), colour="red", size=5) + 
  annotation_custom(tableGrob(mytable, rows=NULL), 
                    xmin=35, xmax=50, ymin=-2.5, ymax=-1)
```

[image: Plot image]

Please see the [gridExtra Wiki](https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki/tableGrob).

Answer (score 1):

@user3206440: I found a work-around that removes row numbers.  I formatted my data as a matrix, assigned column names, then had tableGrob call that directly.  Whenever I had tableGrob call it as a data frame, the row name persisted.

Below is an example.  I'm sure there's an easier way to deal with the chisq.test output

```
chivalues <- chisq.test(chitable)
chidf <- matrix(c(unlist(c(round(as.numeric(chivalues[1]), 2),
                    chivalues[2], round(as.numeric(chivalues[3]), 5), numcells))),
                   nrow = 1, ncol = 4, byrow = FALSE)
colnames(chidf) <- c("Chi-Squared", "DF", "P Value", "Total Cells")
```

And then later...

```
annotation_custom(tableGrob(chidf), xmin=2, xmax=6, ymin=700, ymax=800)
```