# R version ggplot with extra table 3.2.1

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to achieve exactly same info like answer in below link

[Adding table within the plotting region of a ggplot in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318120/adding-table-within-the-plotting-region-of-a-ggplot-in-r)
but I am trying to put my extra table info in on the top left corner with header on it.I tried changing xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax values but it did not work. My X axis is a factor I think that added another layer of complexity. Can somebody help.

I tried following below suggestion too but unfortunately there is no grid() package anymore.

http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/

Your help is appreciated.

**Edit: Code copied from comments**

```
ggplot(data=AMIClean, aes(x=Month_Year_Final, y=Observed_Rate, group=1)) 
+ geom_line(aes(group=1),colour = "forestgreen")+ geom_point(size=3, colour="black") 
+ xlab("Month Year(N=Denominator Cases)") + ylab("Readmission Rate(%)") 
+ ggtitle("AMI Trend (%)")+ theme_bw() 
+ theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 
+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) 
+ annotation_custom(tableGrob(AMITableCurrent),xmax=24,xmin=0 ymin=0, ymax=30)
```

Comment: Of there was no grid package there would be no ggplot2 package. The latter depends on the former.

Comment: Hello Roland, if I go to package list. I can see gridBase,gridDebug,....gridSVG but not grid. I am new on R. AM I missing basic steps here? This is my steps in windows 7 64 bit version Packages>>choose mirror>>and scroll down till you find grid

Comment: # here is my code                                                        ggplot(data=AMIClean, aes(x=Month_Year_Final, y=Observed_Rate, group=1)) +
    geom_line(aes(group=1),colour = "forestgreen")+
    geom_point(size=3, colour="black") +
   xlab("Month Year(N=Denominator Cases)") +
   ylab("Readmission Rate(%)") +
   ggtitle("AMI  Trend (%)")+
   theme_bw()+
   theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
    annotation_custom(tableGrob(AMITableCurrent),xmax=24,xmin=0 ymin=0, ymax=30)

Comment: @user2612244 Familiarize yourself with how to post code on this site. Dumping it into the comments makes it reallllllly hard to read. There are tutorials on how to ask good questions here.

Comment: @user2612244 As for the grid package, it does still exist. Did you try to install it by running `library(grid)`? You need to do `install.packages(grid)` first

Comment: grid comes with R by default. https://github.com/wch/r-source/tree/trunk/src/library/grid

Comment: Just loaded and one step ahead. Thank you everybody for the comment. I will update once I am able to move forward.

Comment: I did it. For some reason I can not post my code. I was confused about x and y min and max but it makes sense perfectly. Thank you @senor for your help. I promise I will make my document better moving forward.

Comment: you probably mean to attach `gridExtra` in this case; that's where a `tableGrob` function is defined (not `grid`).

Answer (score 0):

```
# Here is my code. Again Thank you everybody. 
  ggplot(data=AMIClean, aes(x=Month_Year_Final, y=Observed_Rate, group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=1),colour = "forestgreen")+
  geom_point(size=3, colour="black") +
  xlab("Month Year(N=Denominator Cases)") +
  ylab("Readmission Rate(%)") +
  ggtitle("AMI Readmission Trend (%)")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  annotation_custom(tableGrob(AMI_Inset),xmin=17, xmax=22, ymin=29, ymax=30)
```