# Plotting a table from dataframe values using both ggplot2 and gridExtra packages in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I am trying to plot a table with the values from a dataframe. I am not sure of what approach to take using [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2).

I am also trying one approach using [gridextra](/questions/tagged/gridextra)::`grid.table()` and `tableGrob()` functions and both are working similarly.

For example: I plot `iris` as a table using following code

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
d <- head(iris, 3)
g <- tableGrob(d)
grid.draw(g)
```

When I plot this data using `grid.draw`, why I am getting row numbers 1 to 3 along with the table and how can I work on removing these numbers and change font type and background colors. Please guide!

Also guide me to the approach using `ggplot2`

Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: `grid.draw()` from [tag:grid] ? Please add the usual `require` or `library` calls to your code, and see my suggested edits

Comment: yes `grid.draw()` is from grid

Comment: Have a look at `?tableGrob`

Comment: @Mikko I have already mentioned `tableGrob`. I have an issue that row numbers are appearing along side the table using this approach and I don't want that

Comment: If you read the manual page, you will notice that the second argument to `tableGrob` controls the printing of row numbers: use `tableGrob(d, rows = NULL)`. On the same page you will also notice that there is a `theme` argument that controls font type etc.

Comment: If you want to integrate the table in a `ggplot` directly, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318120/adding-table-within-the-plotting-region-of-a-ggplot-in-r

Comment: @ Mikko thanks row names are removed. I am trying to use base_family arguments but it is giving some errors, I am not sure how can I use it. Also the link you shared is not what I want, I want table as an output and not a graph.