# How to add a table to a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, flextable, patchwork

I am trying to combine (in a single chart) a regular `ggplot` chart with a table obtained with `flextable`.

Consider the following example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

mydf <- tibble(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,4),
               b = c(4,4,4,3,3,3))

p1 <- mydf %>% ggplot(aes(x = a, y = b, color = as.factor(b))) + geom_point()

p2 <- mydf %>% flextable::flextable()
```

`p2` looks like

[image]

but unfortunately I cannot combine it with `p1`

```
> p1 + p2
Error: Don't know how to add p2 to a plot
```

What can we do?
Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding table within the plotting region of a ggplot in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318120/adding-table-within-the-plotting-region-of-a-ggplot-in-r)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use fonction `flextable::as_raster` to get a raster from a flextable and then add with `annotation_custom` to an empty ggplot object.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(flextable)
library(grid)
library(cowplot)
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- tibble(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,4),
               b = c(4,4,4,3,3,3))

p1 <- mydf %>% ggplot(aes(x = a, y = b, color = as.factor(b))) + geom_point()

ft_raster <- mydf %>% flextable::flextable() %>% 
  as_raster()

p2 <- ggplot() + 
  theme_void() + 
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(ft_raster), xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf)

cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow = 2, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(4, 1) )
```

[image]

Documentation is here: https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/offcran/images.html

Comment: thanks!! but i am trying to add the table as if it was a plot (not as an annotation that is). how can i get that?

Comment: in other words the table should take as much space as the plot (side by side)

Comment: If I understand correctly, with patchwork, you would have to use `p1 + p2` or with cowplot `cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow = 1, ncol = 2)`. Is that what you want?

Comment: ha actually David the big issue is that as_raster needs `install_phantomjs()` which is deprecated and hard to install at work. Do you see any other working alternatives?

Comment: using webshot2 is an alternative

Comment: it was missing from as_raster args but now its ok - use github version

Answer (score 10):

[`tableGrob`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html) from the `gridExtra` package works too

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

mydf <- tibble(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,4),
               b = c(4,4,4,3,3,3))

p1 <- mydf %>% ggplot(aes(x = a, y = b, color = as.factor(b))) + geom_point()

mytheme <- gridExtra::ttheme_default(
  core = list(padding = unit(c(2.5, 2.5), "mm")))
tbl <- tableGrob(mydf, theme = mytheme, rows = NULL)

grid.arrange(p1,
             tbl,
             nrow = 2,
             as.table = TRUE,
             heights = c(4, 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Following 2 ways are there

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpmisc)

mydf <- tibble(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,4),
               b = c(4,4,4,3,3,3))

p1 <- mydf %>% ggplot(aes(x = a, y = b, color = as.factor(b))) + geom_point()
p1 + annotate(geom = "table", x = 4.5, y = 3.5, label = list(mydf), 
           vjust = 1, hjust = 0)
```

[image]

```
p1 + geom_table_npc(data = mydf, label = list(mydf),npcx = 0.05, npcy = 0.90, hjust = 0, vjust = 1)
```

[image]