# Is there a faster way than flextable to add tables to ggplot objects?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking for a good way to add a table to a ggplot object. So far, I've tried ggplot2::annotate, ggpmisc::geom_table, and flextable::flextable.

As discussed [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60349028/how-to-add-a-table-to-a-ggplot), flextable will do the job, [but it is very slow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zry3x.jpg) (~5-10 seconds per table). This makes it less than ideal for adding multiple tables to a ggplot object.

I tried ggplot2::annotate, thinking that I could just lay out the table using tab characters (\t) and newlines (\n). It turns out that the annotate function [ignores the tab characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBtaG.jpg), so I don't get a table.

Next I tried ggpmisc::geom_table. This gives a layout pretty close to what I want, but for some reason, when the text is left justified, it always [cuts off the right hand edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzCbV.jpg) of the longest line.

Is there a better way to add tables to ggplot objects? Or a way to repair one of my failed attempts?

I've also had suggestions from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/nmasau/adding_tables_to_ggplot_objects/) to try ggtable or tableGrob, but so far I've made even less progress getting either of those to produce a ggplot object.

Here's the code I used to generate the tables in the images:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
library(tibble)
library(flextable)

# ggplot2::annotate
annotate_table <- paste0(
  0,    '\t', 'ggplot2::annotate ignores tabs',                 '\n',
  1,    '\t', 'one',                                            '\n',
  2,    '\t', 'two',                                            '\n',
  7777, '\t', 'seven thousand seven hundred and seventy seven', '\n'
)
t_annotate <- ggplot() +
  annotate('text', x = 0, y = 0, label = annotate_table) +
  theme_void()
t_annotate

# ggpmisc::geom_table
my_df <- data.frame(
  a = c(0, 1, 2, 7777),
  b = c('ggpmisc::geom_table cuts off text', 'one', 'two', 'seven thousand seven hundred and seventy seven')
)
my_tibble <- tibble(x = 0, y = 0, tbl = list(my_df))
t_geom_table <- ggplot(my_df) +
  geom_table(
    data    = my_tibble,
    mapping = aes(x = 0, y = 0, label = tbl),
    table.hjust = 'left',
    table.colnames = FALSE,
    table.theme = ttheme_gtminimal
  ) +
  theme_void()
t_geom_table

# flextable::flextable
my_df <- data.frame(
  a = c(0, 1, 2, 7777),
  b = c('flextable::flextable is slow', 'one', 'two', 'seven thousand seven hundred and seventy seven')
)
my_ft <- flextable(my_df)
my_ft <- delete_part(my_ft, 'header')
my_ft <- border_remove(my_ft)
my_ft <- autofit(my_ft)
my_ft <- as_raster(my_ft)  # This line is very slow
t_flextable <- ggplot() +
  annotation_custom(grid::rasterGrob(my_ft)) +
  theme_void()
t_flextable
```

Comment: Just a few minutes ago I collected some links in a comment [on this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67742738/903061). Don't know if it will help, but some more examples at the very least.