# R: Add a table1 to ggdraw figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a figure that includes a table1 (here is my example table1: [mtcars table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H51u.png)) and some plots using ggdraw.

```
library(htmlTable)
library(table1)
library(tibble)
library(Hmisc)
library(cowplot)
mtcars
table_mtcars <- table1(~cyl +disp + hp, data = mtcars)
table_mtcars
mtcars_plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = disp)) +
  geom_jitter()
mtcars_plot

mtcars_plot2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = hp)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  ggtitle('with hp')
mtcars_plot2

ggdraw() + 
  draw_plot(table_mtcars, x = 0, y = .5, width = .5, height = .5) +
  draw_plot(mtcars_plot, x = .5, y = .5, width = .5, height = .5) +
  draw_plot(mtcars_plot2, x = 0, y = 0, width = 1, height = 0.5) +
  draw_plot_label(label = c("A", "B", "C"), size = 15,
                  x = c(0, 0.5, 0), y = c(1, 1, 0.5))
```

Unfortunately, only the plots show up here: [ggdraw example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5v1E.png). Is there a way to insert a table into a ggdraw image? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you clarify how you made `table_mtcars`? I don't recognize the function you're using `table1()`. What package is it from?

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! I have the packages library(htmlTable)
library(table1)
library(tibble)
library(Hmisc)

Comment: Ok - it might be tricky to incorporate an HTML table into the layout. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60349028/how-to-add-a-table-to-a-ggplot) question for more.

Comment: It looks like it's possible with {flextable} using `as_raster()` and then add it with the plots using {patchwork}

Answer (score 2):

One option to achieve your desired result using `cowplot` and `table1` would be to convert your table to a `flextable` via `table1::t1flex` which allows to follow the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60349028/how-to-add-a-table-to-a-ggplot) referenced by @DanAdams in his comment, i.e. converting the flextable to a raster image via `flextable::as_raster` and adding it to the plot grid as a `grid::rasterGrob`.

Note: I added some padding around the table by adjusting the `width` and `height` and the position. But you could set that as you like.

```r
library(table1)
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(flextable)

table_mtcars <- table1(~cyl +disp + hp, data = mtcars) %>% 
  t1flex() %>% 
  flextable::as_raster()

mtcars_plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = disp)) +
  geom_jitter()

mtcars_plot2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = hp)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  ggtitle('with hp')

ggdraw() + 
  draw_plot(grid::rasterGrob(table_mtcars), x = 0.025, y = .525, width = .45, height = .45) +
  draw_plot(mtcars_plot, x = .5, y = .5, width = .5, height = .5) +
  draw_plot(mtcars_plot2, x = 0, y = 0, width = 1, height = 0.5) +
  draw_plot_label(label = c("A", "B", "C"), size = 15,
                  x = c(0, 0.5, 0), y = c(1, 1, 0.5))
```

[image]