# R ggplot - ecdf chart - adding table with summary stats inside/outside plot area

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

With data like below, that plots the CDF of two different columns in the data frame, need to add some part of the summary stats to the plot.

To plot the CDF I do the following

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(height1 = round(rnorm(200, mean=60, sd=15)), height2 = round(rnorm(200, mean=55, sd=10)))
df %>% pivot_longer(c('height1', 'height2'), names_to = "Group", values_to = "value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(value, colour = Group)) + 
  stat_ecdf()
```

The above gives the CDF

[image: Basic CDF]

I need to add some summary stats to this plot and need help with getting the following 2 representations.

The summary stats table is generated as

```
tbl = df %>% pivot_longer(c('height1', 'height2'), names_to = "Group", values_to = "value") %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarize(Samples = n(), Median=median(value, na.rm=T), Pctl_10th=quantile(value, 0.1, na.rm=T))
```

One thing with `Samples` is that it should omit `NA`s.

1. CDF with Summary Stats ***inside*** the plot positioned at the bottom left corner
2. CDF with Summary Stats ***outside*** the plot positioned at the bottom left corner

[image: CDF with Summary Stats inside the plot positioned at the bottom left corner]
[image: CDF with Summary Stats outside the plot positioned at the bottom left corner]

Looking for an answer that covers the following

1. Using [ggpmisc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpmisc/vignettes/user-guide.html#geom_table-and-stat_fmt_table) , `tableGrob` packages or other mainline package
2. Flexibility in specifying the position of the table relative to bottom-right or bottom-left or top-right or top-left corners of the graph or the whole plot area ( as in the second example).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318120/adding-table-within-the-plotting-region-of-a-ggplot-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can position the plot and the table over an empty plot using [`ggpmisc`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpmisc/vignettes/user-guide.html#geom_table-and-stat_fmt_table).
To facilitate positioning, coordinates of the empty plot are set to (0,1) range.
You can define position of each object in the tibble (see below) and adjust sizing/positioning with following parameters :

- `vp.height` and `vp.width` define width and heigth of each plot (from 0 to 1 = 100%)
- `hjust` and `vjust` define how the table is aligned to its position : 0 is left/bottom adjustment, 1 is top/right adjustment

```
set.seed(1234)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

df <- data.frame(height1 = round(rnorm(200, mean=60, sd=15)), height2 = round(rnorm(200, mean=55, sd=10)))

tb <- df %>% pivot_longer(c('height1', 'height2'), names_to = "Group", values_to = "value") %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarize(Samples = n(), Median=median(value, na.rm=T), Pctl_10th=quantile(value, 0.1, na.rm=T))


p <- df %>% pivot_longer(c('height1', 'height2'), names_to = "Group", values_to = "value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(value, colour = Group)) + 
  stat_ecdf()

# x and y values define the position of the lower left corner of eah object
data.plot <- tibble(x = 0, y = 0, p = list(p ))
data.tb <- tibble(x = 0.6, y = 0, tbl = list(tb))

# Set up the plot
# vp.width defines the relative width of the plot : here = 70% (including legend)
# vp.height defines the relative height of the plot : here = 80%
# hjust defines table horizontal alignement, set to 0 so that x controls left position
# vjust defines table vertical alignement, set to 0 so that y control bottom position

# On the side of the plot
ggplot() + xlim(c(0,1)) + ylim(c(0,1))  +   theme_void() +
  geom_plot(data = data.plot, aes(x, y, label = p,vp.width = .7,vp.height = 0.8))+
  geom_table(data=data.tb, aes(x,y,label = tbl,hjust=0,vjust=0))

# Inside the plot
data.tb <- tibble(x = 0.4, y = 0.1, tbl = list(tb))

ggplot() + xlim(c(0,1)) + ylim(c(0,1))  +   theme_void() +
  geom_plot(data = data.plot, aes(x, y, label = p,vp.width = 0.95,vp.height = 0.8))+
  geom_table(data=data.tb, aes(x,y,label = tbl,hjust=0,vjust=0))
```

Note that `ggmisc` doesn't control table width, so it's difficult to perfectly align plot border with table border and has to be done manually depending on figure size.
[image]
[image]

Comment: how abt the first representation where the table needs to be inside - comments in the code on the steps would be helpful

Comment: also for the table what does `hjust=0.3,vp.width=0.3` mean - is it 0.3 ( units ? ) to the right of the chart ?

Comment: gets the warning `Ignoring unknown aesthetics: vp.width`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, sorry for the warning : table doesn't use vp.width, this is only for the plot part. See my edit.