# Add a legend for a geom_text layer to explain labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Consider the following example where a scatter is made and only the "significant" point are colored and labelled.

```
genes <- read.table("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/stephenturner/806e31fce55a8b7175af/raw/1a507c4c3f9f1baaa3a69187223ff3d3050628d4/results.txt", header = TRUE)
genes$Significant <- ifelse(genes$padj < 0.05, "FDR < 0.05", "Not Sig")
ggplot(genes, aes(x = log2FoldChange, y = -log10(pvalue))) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Significant)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "grey")) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) + theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = subset(genes, padj < 0.05),
    aes(label = Gene),
    size = 5,
    box.padding = unit(0.35, "lines"),
    point.padding = unit(0.3, "lines")
  )
```

It yields the following plot
[image: gene significance plot]

Now imagine that the labels are actually acronyms and that they have a real full-length name (e.g., "DOK6" is the acronym for "Duo Ocarino Kayne 6"). Would it be possible to add a legend to the plot where the keys are the labels used on the plot, and the entries are the full-length name of the labels ?

Comment: Perhaps this approach? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318120/adding-table-within-the-plotting-region-of-a-ggplot-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I added `Gene2` for another legend which only shows significant `Gene`.\

Next, `Gene2` was added on the `aes` as a `fill`. (Only `color` would affect the color of points on `geom_point`).\

Finally, `scale_fill_discrete` was added for the second legend. All you need to do is just annotate the full-length name column at `Full names here`.

```
genes$Gene2 <-ifelse(genes$padj<0.05, genes$Gene, NA)
ggplot(genes, aes(x = log2FoldChange, y = -log10(pvalue),
                  fill=Gene2)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Significant)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "grey")) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) + theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = subset(genes, padj < 0.05),
    aes(label = Gene),
    size = 5,
    box.padding = unit(0.35, "lines"),
    point.padding = unit(0.3, "lines")
  ) +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels=paste0(genes$Gene,': ',' Full names here'),
                      name='Significant genes') +
  theme(legend.position = 'right')
```

**Output**
[image]