# Subsetting and highlighting multiple data points in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to produce a bar plot with multiple ranges of data points highlighted differently. The following question here at [r - ggplot2 - highlighting selected points and strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467965/r-ggplot2-highlighting-selected-points-and-strange-behavior) is close to what I want to do except that instead of subsetting and highlighting only one range of datapoints, I want to subset multiple ranges of data points and generate a differentially colored bar plot.

I have used this code (adapted from that question above) to red-highlight a subset of data from 10 to 30.

```
a <- 1:50
b <- rnorm(50)
mydata <- data.frame(a=a,b=b)
mydata[10:30,]
ggplot(mydata,aes(x=a,y=b)) + geom_point(colour="blue") + geom_point(data=mydata[10:30,], aes(x=a, y=b), colour="red")
```

How can I modify the above code to differentially highlight multiple subsets, say, 1:9 (green), 10:30 (red) and 40:50 (cyan)? Another issue is that if I modify that code by changing `geom_point` to `geom_bar` in ggplot to produce a bar plot the code returns an error, `Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that if you want different colors for different subsets of your data these subsets represent different groups. The usual way to deal with this in `ggplot` would to create a group variable. In ggplot you then can easily set the color aesthetic to your group.

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- 1:50
b <- rnorm(50)
mydata <- data.frame(a=a, b=b)
mydata$group        <- "a" 
mydata$group[1:9]   <- "b"
mydata$group[10:30] <- "c"
mydata$group[40:50] <- "d"

ggplot(mydata,aes(x=a,y=b, col = group)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "green", "red", "cyan"), guide = FALSE)
```

[image]
If you want a bar plot you have to set stat = "identity" like this:

```
ggplot(mydata,aes(x=a,y=b, col = group, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "green", "red", "cyan"), guide = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "green", "red", "cyan"), guide = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As @Alex mentionned it, you can use a `group` variable to select the correct colors.

Use `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` and change `color` by `fill` for `geom_bar`:
[image]

```
a <- 1:50
b <- rnorm(50)
mydata <- data.frame(a=a,b=b)
mydata$group        <- "a" 
mydata$group[1:9]   <- "green"
mydata$group[10:30] <- "red"
mydata$group[40:50] <- "cyan"

ggplot(mydata,aes(x=a,y=b, fill = group)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("a" = "black", "green" = "green", "red" = "red", "cyan" = "cyan"), guide = FALSE)
```