# r ggplot geom_point change color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running the code and it works

```
ggplot(data_df, aes(x= RR, y= PPW, col = year)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3, alpha=0.6)
```

Now I am trying to put the mean value of (x,y) on graph en give it another color by adding

```
ggplot(data_df, aes(x= RR, y= PPW, col = year))) + 
  geom_point(size = 3, alpha=0.6) + 
  geom_point(data=data_df, aes(x=mean(RR), y=mean(PPW)) + 
  geom_point(color="red")
```

It works, but the color of all points is now red

If I put color inside aes like these, the mean point get another color, and I see it also in legend

```
ggplot(data_df, aes(x= RR, y= PPW, col = year))) + 
  geom_point(size = 3, alpha=0.6) + 
  geom_point(data=data_df, aes(x=mean(RR), y=mean(PPW), color="red"))
```

I would like to give the color manually. Is it possible?

Comment: It is always easier to answer questions when you provide sample data and in this case example plots. But if I understood correctly you want the plot from your last code block, but without the point in the legend? I see two solutions: Either move the color argument out of the `aes()` call, but still within the same `geom_point()` or add `show.legend = NA` to the second `geom_point()` call to remove the legend entry for the mean points.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [r - ggplot2 - highlighting selected points and strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467965/r-ggplot2-highlighting-selected-points-and-strange-behavior)

Comment: yes indeed. It's not the solution, but I can continue. Thanks @divibisan

Comment: @Mojoesque, thanks. I'll learn how to put data and example plots to question.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing two key points about how `ggplot` manages aesthetics:

1. Each `geom_*` layer will inherit the `aes` settings from the parent `ggplot` call, unless you manually override it. So in you first example, the 3rd `geom_point` inherits the `x` and `y` values from `ggplot`, not the "mean" layer above it, and thus renders a red point on top of each colored point.
2. Values in the `aes` are applied to a scale, not used as is. So when you put `color = 'red'` in the `aes` in your second example, you aren't making the points red, you're saying that color should be determined by a categorical variable (which here is a length 1 vector consisting of the word 'red') based on the `scale_color_*`. You can either add a `scale_color_manual` and set `'red' = 'red'`, so that value renders the desired color, or move the `color=` outside the `aes`, so it is interpreted as is (and will make all points in that layer red).

---

With those points in mind, doing what you want is as simple as moving the `color` outside the `aes`:

```
ggplot(data_df, aes(x= RR, y= PPW, col = year))) + 
    geom_point(size = 3, alpha=0.6) + 
    geom_point(data=data_df, aes(x=mean(RR), y=mean(PPW)), color="red")
```