# How to change colour of points in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `library(tidyverse)`, fix this code by making the point blue instead of red:

```
ggplot(data = mpg) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, colour = "blue"))
```

Not sure where where to input the code to change it to blue instead of red, can anyone explain why it is default red and what the code would look like to change the colour?

Comment: The `colour` argument should be out of the `mapping` argument : `ggplot(data = mpg) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy), colour = "blue")`

Comment: Found out how to change the initial code into blue points but how to I keep the legend in?
Currently looks like:
1. ggplot(data = mpg) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy), color = "blue")

Comment: @Basti how would you keep the legend visible with that?

Comment: This page may help give you some of the answers you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301575/r-ggplot-geom-point-change-color